# Stack Overflow for business questions

Tags: feature-request, site-proposal

Well, it would be nice if entrepreneurs could have a Q&A platform to ask questions on business. In 2012, startups have been a big theme, and many people like me have no experience with starting a business, such as with the legal side of things. The ability to ask business-related questions would be great, as it would be free, and we would get input from professionals with a lot of experience.

It would be cool to have this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There used to be a [Startups](http://onstartups.com/) site but it's [no longer active](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214315/295232). There are over 170 sites active or in beta [on the network](https://stackexchange.com/sites), and more are added as time goes on. If you have an idea for a specific proposal, [there is even a site for that](http://area51.stackexchange.com/)!