# What happened to Startups SE?

Tags: discussion, closed-sites

I really enjoyed that site. I've only posted on it once, but I enjoyed seeing other people's posts and appreciated reading about entrepreneurial dilemmas.

Comment: It was closed because the required community failed to form.

Comment: thats a shame. I can understand how this would be more of an occasional question forum than community...

Comment: It ran out of venture capital^W^Wcommunity involvement and went bust.

Comment: very amuzed that a question like this gets voted down. ahh, the meta experience. :)

Comment: It was resurrected by the community outside of stackexchange at [Bright Journey](http://www.brightjourney.com) and thriving.

Comment: What SE site should be used instead for business-related questions?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217793/159916

Comment: There's a new SE for startups in private beta. That is, @DaveA, if you still care :]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The Startups Stack Exchange site didn't make it; the community required to sustain it beyond Beta never materialized.

See the [Area51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6243/startup-business), where you can download an archive of the site as well.

Comment: Some of the community that did participate seemed to feel a lack of focus/guidance. The answers would wander into brow-beating and knocking those who asked questions. That likely brought a chilling effect to askers (sure did for me). That spells doom. Cautionary tale I suppose.

Comment: Fun fact: the area 51 stats seem mostly fine. Get rid of these stats already!

Answer (score 20):

Apparently it was resurrected as [Bright Journey](http://www.brightjourney.com/). I just got an email about this.

Comment: Did the email have any information about the software they use? I poked around on the site and could not recognize the engine nor find any information about it. They acknowledge SE source with a link to Area 51 ("Made possible by SE"), and that's it.

Comment: @user127096, the email didn't say. I was wondering about that too.

Comment: @user127096 Looking at their [roadmap](http://www.brightjourney.com/roadmap/), I think they've built it from scratch.

Comment: @KennyEvitt Did you provide them your e-mail? How did they contact you using it?

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi Are emails provided in the data-dump for closed sites? Because that's what they used to reconstruct the site...

Comment: @hichris123 No, they do include the e-mail hash (used for Gravatar) which we no longer include in data dumps though.

Comment: Hi guys, I'm one of the contributors to Bright Journey. We did indeed build it from scratch and can answer any questions you might have.

Comment: If your questions won't fit in here, feel free to contact me directly at team {AT} brightjourney .com

Comment: @user127096 We'll eventually be making our software open source on GitHub for anyone to use. Feel free to email me and I'll alert you when it's released.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi, I did not provide them my email; at least not that I remember. I have no idea how they got it (if I didn't give it to them).

Comment: @KennyEvitt according to [their post on Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7231538) alongside a comment they posted here (but removed) they reverse engineered the e-mails from hashes in the data dump which were for gravatars.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi Here is the [full Hacker News thread](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7230872) for reference.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi Strange. You mention it as if it's a secret, when they have been very upfront and public about it with everyone. Kudos to those guys for keeping the startup community alive.

Comment: @Jill.G I'm not mentioning it as if it's a secret, I'm simply stating that they deleted the comment. I will say that it definitely shocked me, and I'm very happy that someone didn't reverse engineer my own e-mail address from a public data dump that should've been sanitized :)

Comment: Um, everyone's email hash is online and several people have reverse engineered the hashes of the entire stackoverflow audience... A user was able to get 10% of the entire userbase's email addresses: http://www.developer.it/post/gravatars-why-publishing-your-email-s-hash-is-not-a-good-idea

Comment: They have been very vocal and open on hacker news. And [here's a month old thread](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/12807/why-should-any-of-us-contribute-when-stack-exchange-will-throw-away-our-work-wit)

Comment: @Jill.G Yep, and we've been working on removing MD5 e-mails and safeguarding that line of attack. I just feel that it's unethical to use that sort of attack as a business growth perspective. I also posted the hacker news thread here myself...

Comment: "attack"? I'm not sure if you understand fully what this is. But I guess any discussion here will be biased since you're a stack exchange employee.

Comment: These threads show exactly how the community feels: [here](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/12807/why-should-any-of-us-contribute-when-stack-exchange-will-throw-away-our-work-wit), [here](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/12607/site-on-startups-is-closed-what-to-do-now/) and [here](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/12662/how-is-startup-business-going-to-be-different-from-the-close-startups-proposal)

Comment: Just to clarify, @Jill: this is probably the one GOOD use for that email hash (apart from Gravatar, of course, which is what it was *intended* for). And it *REALLY SUCKS* that a handful of people decided mass cracking + spamming of email hashes was worth investing in, because otherwise we could've kept this option open for the future - it's ALWAYS a good idea to give folks a way to prove they wrote something. Frankly, it pisses me off that "privacy" is winning out over "attribution" in these discussions - but, that's what folks care about right now, so be it. If you have good ideas, post 'em.

Comment: @Shog9 This is from FIVE years ago: http://www.developer.it/post/gravatars-why-publishing-your-email-s-hash-is-not-a-good-idea

Comment: @Shog9 I'm not sure why it would have taken this long to just save the gravatars locally and serve them vs using email hashes. And you're right that bright journey was probably the only good use for the hashes. They wouldn't have been able to bring the closed community back to life without it.

Comment: Yeah, I know @Jill - that post links to [this thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21117/is-using-gravatar-a-security-risk). This has been a known form of abuse for about as long as SO has been around - but it took 4+ years for someone to decide to take that information and create a business centered on being a GIANT DICK with that data. We'd previously discussed the other *positive* use for this information [in a comment thread regarding previous site closures](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/04/when-a-site-grows-quiet/) - it struck me as a nice bonus, and I'm glad it was useful

Comment: @Shog9 Who are you referring to with the profanity?

Comment: A certain company who decided to extract a bunch of email addresses and then harass SO users, @Jill. Also, vulgarity not profanity. Also, sorry - nothing to do with you, just something that depresses me since it means the next Bright Journey will be a bit harder to set up.

Comment: @Shog9 Ah, I see. In that context I misinterpreted as you referring that to Bright Journey. My apologies.

Comment: Hmph. I come to the site and the first thing I see is spam. From today, just one, correctly tagged and with valid grammar, mind you, but still spam a couple hours old - with eight views.

Answer (score 10):

It didn't have enough ongoing activity, so it was closed down. It seems there were only a very small handful of regulars who were maintaining the site.

There are more details on the [Startup Business](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6243/startup-business) site proposal on Area 51.

(Note that there is also a [new proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/62811/startup-business) to try and get a new community of users around the topic.)

Comment: that's interesting. I wonder if the forum could have value without a hard-core community. The incubator-style questions seemed to serve a purpose.

Comment: @DaveA I didn't frequent the site, so I'm not familiar with the incubator-style questions. They are still available in the data dump though.

Answer (score 6):

As of 2014, there's currently a [new proposal called "Startup"](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/62811/startup-business) in Area51.

---

As of August 2014, it is in public beta. Visit [startups.stackexchange.com](http://startups.stackexchange.com).

---

As of December 2017, it will be [shut down again](https://startups.meta.stackexchange.com/q/345/4803).

Comment: Why would they do that? If it failed the first time, why would you think "oh let's just start another site and put all the same questions back on it" would change anything? That sounds like a horrific plan.

Comment: @animuson, Why do you say they failed? There are good questions and there are good answers. It's only closed because we don't get the minimum 5 questions/day on average (4.8 was the number). Closed != Failed.

Comment: "Failed" to make a community big enough for interests of SE. In my opinion, succeeded in other very intriguing ways

Comment: @Pacerier Startups wasn't closed because it didn't hit a somewhat arbitrary questions-per-day number. It had large systemic issues like a lack of cohesive, engaged community, lack of moderation (except by a handful of people), abysmal user retention, and so on. There's no harm in trying again - and we have active sites right now that were restarts of closed proposals - but keep in mind that the goal can't be "get a new site and import all old posts". That's just not how this sort of thing works.

Comment: @AdamLear, Do you mean Brightjourney will exist alongside Startups-SE if the new Startups-SE gets traction?

Comment: @Pacerier We don't run Bright Journey. I have no idea what its owners plans are.

Comment: @Adam whatever that "Bright Journey" was, it's now pretty much dead, while the SE site isn't really thriving, but is alive and kicking. SE wins. :-D

Comment: @Sha Let's call it a tie.

Comment: Saved a copy of that post on [web archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20171208142947/https://startups.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345/startups-stack-exchange-will-be-closing-on-december-11th), as the question would go away along with the site.

Comment: @CrazyIvan huh. Isn't it the first time a public beta is being shut down due to lack of activity? I guess they will close many other sites now, Health.SE for sure and others with low activity.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Far from the first. There were Startups v1, Arabic Language, Theoretical Physics, Literature v1, Astronomy v1, Economics v1, [and others](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/04/25/when-a-site-grows-quiet/)

Comment: @CrazyIvan oh. So only graduated site was never closed down?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Correct.