# What is Brightjourney?

Tags: discussion, clone

I recently came across [Brightjourney](http://www.brightjourney.com/).

Its design feels a lot like S.E. communities, and it does indeed pay tribute to SE at the bottom of the page:

[image]

It makes it seem like the website is a stackexchange community or beta community, but I cannot find anything about it on the area51 website, and the login I use for S.E. doesn't work with it. It also seems to have a different team of developers.

So, I am curious to understand if the people behind Brightjourney just took the framework behind SE to make something different but that looks and feels the same... or if it's a beta in the works of some kind?

I wasn't aware that SE was sharing its resources and would be interested in knowing more if that was the case.

Comment: http://www.brightjourney.com looks like a scraper site.

Comment: *"the login I use for S.E. doesn't work with it"* I hope you trust them not to log such things. https://xkcd.com/792/

Comment: I went on the site while already logged into SE and realized I wasn't logged in, which made me come to this conclusion. I didn't type my SE login in there and neither should you ;)

Comment: @fabriced Hey! That site doesn't have spam prevention systems like SE... :D Another reason why I am glad to be a Stack Exchangite.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I doesn't appear to be a scraper site, or really powered by Stack Exchange at all, just a sort-of knock-off inspired by a failed Area 51 site.

From [What happened to Startups SE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214315/what-happened-to-startups-se):

> Apparently it was resurrected as Bright Journey. I just got an email about this. - [Kenny Evitt](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/221567)

Which isn't quite accurate, more of a site intended to replace the failed Area 51 proposal I think, comments include more details:

> Hi guys, I'm one of the contributors to Bright Journey. We did indeed build it from scratch and can answer any questions you might have. – [user3188544](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/252307/user3188544), [Feb 17 '14 at 19:10](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214315/what-happened-to-startups-se#comment719793_221567)

> We'll eventually be making our software open source on GitHub for anyone to use. Feel free to email me and I'll alert you when it's released. – [user3188544](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/252307/user3188544), [Feb 17 '14 at 19:17](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214315/what-happened-to-startups-se#comment719795_221567)

Answer (score 4):

Looks like one of the *many* clones of the Stack Exchange model.

OSQA and AskBot (which is derived from OSQA) are such codebases - they mimic the UI and basic workflows of the platform.

This site looks like it wrote its own version.

It is not part of the Stack Exchange network - there is no top bar, isn't using the Stack Exchange logo and, as you noticed, doesn't share login details.

They have not taken the framework behind SE (which is close source and not available outside of the company) and SE isn't sharing its resources.

I can only assume the SE mention (no idea why they would link to Area51 of all things) is because it provided inspiration and a basis that they copied from.

Comment: They did restore the Answers.Onstartups data dump back in the day, if I recall correctly. Which is sort of why we do data dumps, so that's fine, except that then they also emailed users, which was how we finally got rid of the gravatar hashes in data dumps. :/ (Disclaimer: this is true assuming my memory is holding up.)